# @Grab annotation working from JSR 223

Tags: groovy, scriptengine

I have a groovy script that I would to run automatically, ideally using JSR 223 (Scripting on the Java Platform).

The @Grab resolve process is working from console as well as when I execute it as external process. It however does not work using ScriptEngine from Groovy 1.8.6. The problem is that ScriptEngine will not respect the @Grab and I'm getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport.

Anybody has solved this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

**GrabTestJSR233.java:**

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine ;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager ;

public class GrabTestJSR223 {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager() ;
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName( "groovy" ) ;
    String script = "@Grab( 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6' )\n" +
                    "import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils\n"+
                    "\n" +
                    "println StringUtils.join( 'a', 'b', 'c' )" ;

    engine.eval( script ) ;
  }
}
```

Compile with:

```
javac GrabTestJSR223.java
```

Then, run with:

```
java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/lib/*:. GrabTestJSR223
```

And I get the output:

```
abc
```

Comment: The problem was that I was not setting the classpath and Maven does not either (Ivy dependency was missing). After manual dependency to Ivy, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

tyvm ...
adding

> compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '3.0.1'
>
> compile group: 'org.apache.ivy', name: 'ivy', version: '2.5.0'

in my build.gradle did the trick.  **ivy** is needed at "**runtime**" for **Grapes** to work